# How to find all tuple permutations in a list?

Tags: python

I want to create all possible permutations of tuples in a list using python. For example, take the list

```
my_list = [(None, 1), (None,1), (None,1)]
```

I want the generate a list of (2!)^n lists where 2! is the number of combinations of the tuple arrangements and

n represents the number of tuples in the list. So the above list should produce 8 distinct lists, for example.

I can achieve this if I use the `itertools` python module in the following way:

```
from itertools import permutations
my_list = [(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)]
all_permutations = []
for k in permutations(my_list[0]):
    for j in permutations(my_list[1]):
        for i in permutations(my_list[2]):
            all_permutations.append([k,j,i])

print(all_permutations)
```

and I get the expected output:

```
[[(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)],
 [(None, 1), (None, 1), (1, None)],
 [(None, 1), (1, None), (None, 1)],
 [(None, 1), (1, None), (1, None)],
 [(1, None), (None, 1), (None, 1)],
 [(1, None), (None, 1), (1, None)],
 [(1, None), (1, None), (None, 1)],
 [(1, None), (1, None), (1, None)]]
```

How do I generalize this result to a list of n tuples of size 2 without having to hard code the for-loop? The closest thing I've seen was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74414916/how-to-find-all-permutations-in-a-list-of-sets-except-permutations-from-own-set), but it doesn't quite do what I need. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Recursion is a step towards solving this problem.

Comment: Use a recursive function to generate all possible permutations of the tuples in the list. The idea is to generate permutations for each tuple and then recursively combine them with the permutations of the remaining tuples.

Comment: The task/example would be clearer if you used six different values (like the numbers 1 to 6) instead of only None and 1 multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is useful here (if I understand your question correctly). `itertools.product` is the equivalent to your nested loops and takes as argument multiple iterables. So `[permutations(x) for x in my_list]` (or `map(permutations, my_list)`) generically creates a list of iterables from `my_list` and the asterisk `*` turns that into separate arguments for `product`.

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, product
>>> my_list = [(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)]
>>> list(product(*[permutations(x) for x in my_list]))
[((None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)),
 ((None, 1), (None, 1), (1, None)),
 ((None, 1), (1, None), (None, 1)),
 ((None, 1), (1, None), (1, None)),
 ((1, None), (None, 1), (None, 1)),
 ((1, None), (None, 1), (1, None)),
 ((1, None), (1, None), (None, 1)),
 ((1, None), (1, None), (1, None))]
>>> my_list = [(None, 1), ("a", "b"), (1,2,3), (None, 4)]
>>> list(product(*[permutations(x) for x in my_list]))
[((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (1, 2, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (1, 2, 3), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (1, 3, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (1, 3, 2), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (2, 1, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (2, 1, 3), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (2, 3, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (2, 3, 1), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (3, 1, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (3, 1, 2), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (3, 2, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (3, 2, 1), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (1, 2, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (1, 2, 3), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (1, 3, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (1, 3, 2), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (2, 1, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (2, 1, 3), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (2, 3, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (2, 3, 1), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (3, 1, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (3, 1, 2), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (3, 2, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('b', 'a'), (3, 2, 1), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (1, 2, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (1, 2, 3), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (1, 3, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (1, 3, 2), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (2, 1, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (2, 1, 3), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (2, 3, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (2, 3, 1), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (3, 1, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (3, 1, 2), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (3, 2, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('a', 'b'), (3, 2, 1), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (1, 2, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (1, 2, 3), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (1, 3, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (1, 3, 2), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (2, 1, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (2, 1, 3), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (2, 3, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (2, 3, 1), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (3, 1, 2), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (3, 1, 2), (4, None)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (3, 2, 1), (None, 4)),
 ((1, None), ('b', 'a'), (3, 2, 1), (4, None))]
>>> list(product(*map(permutations, my_list))
[((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (1, 2, 3), (None, 4)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (1, 2, 3), (4, None)),
 ((None, 1), ('a', 'b'), (1, 3, 2), (None, 4)),
 [same output...]
```

Unlike your example, the above returns a list of tuples (and not a list of lists). Imho, tuples are more appropriate, but if you insist that you need lists, you can of course also convert them, using:

```
[list(tup) for tup in product(*[permutations(x) for x in my_list])]
```

or

```
list(map(list, product(*map(permutations, my_list))))
```

Comment: Incredible. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is using recursion. Follow an approach that can you use.

```
from itertools import permutations

def generate_permutations(my_list, current_index=0, current_permutation=None):
    if current_permutation is None:
        current_permutation = []

    if current_index == len(my_list):
        return [current_permutation[:]]

    all_permutations = []
    for perm in permutations(my_list[current_index]):
        current_permutation.append(perm)
        all_permutations.extend(generate_permutations(my_list, current_index + 1, current_permutation))
        current_permutation.pop()

    return all_permutations

my_list = [(None, 1), (None, 1), (None, 1)]
all_permutations = generate_permutations(my_list)
print(all_permutations)
```

I understand that you want a fully recursive approach, but maintaining the current functionality requires at least one iteration for all possible permutations of the current element. Therefore, the part of the code that generates all permutations with the current element needs some kind of loop or iteration. The recursive approach is used to generate permutations of the remaining parts of the list.

If you get some questions about recursion you can visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Remember there are some pros and cons when you use recursion

| Aspect | Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Clarity | Recursive code can be more elegant and easy to understand, especially for problems with inherently recursive structures or logic. | Recursion can be less intuitive for some developers and may require a deeper understanding. |
| Readability | Recursive solutions can lead to cleaner and more concise code, reducing the need for repetitive loops and conditionals. | Excessive recursion can make the code harder to read, understand, and maintain. |
| Problem Solving | Well-suited for problems that can be naturally divided into smaller, similar subproblems, like tree traversal or divide-and-conquer algorithms. | Inefficient for certain problems, leading to higher memory consumption and stack overflow errors if not properly optimized. |
| Code Reusability | Recursive functions can be reused in various contexts, promoting modular and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) coding practices. | Recursive function calls can add overhead and decrease performance compared to iterative solutions. |
| Functional Style | Fits well with functional programming paradigms and can lead to more declarative and composable code. | May not be the most efficient choice for problems that have straightforward iterative solutions. |
| Tail Recursion | In languages that support tail recursion optimization, recursive solutions can be just as efficient as their iterative counterparts. | Not all programming languages or environments support tail recursion optimization. |
| Stack Management | Useful for maintaining state and context, especially in backtracking algorithms and tree traversal. | Deeply nested recursion can lead to a large call stack, potentially causing a stack overflow error. |
| Mathematical Base | Naturally mirrors mathematical induction and recursive definitions, making it appropriate for certain mathematical algorithms. | Not always the most natural or efficient approach for solving practical problems in software development. |

Comment: *"I understand that you want a fully recursive approach,"* The questioner actually didn't specify that.